# SOAP Service fails with AJAX call but works fine in SOAPUI

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap, cors

Invoking soap service throws 404 error but works fine in SOAP UI. Somewhere I found this could be due to CORS problem so I set the header to 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' but no luck

Below is how I am calling service

```
let _this=this;
  var webServiceURL = 'http://localhost:8082/ode/processes/WS_Invocation.WS_InvocationPort';


var soapMessage = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.invocation.tps"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ws:WS_InvocationRequest><ws:input>1</ws:input><ws:input1>Mohan</ws:input1></ws:WS_InvocationRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>'

  $.ajax({
        url: _this.webServiceURL, 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml", 
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
        data: _this.soapMessage, 
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
        success: _this.OnSuccess, 
        error: _this.OnError
    });
```

Below is successful response from SOAP UI
[image]

Comment: Remove the `headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }` from your `$.ajax` call. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a *response* header that servers must send. Sending it as a request header isn’t going to solve any problem for you. After removing that, to get more help, use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45309437/edit to edit/update your question and add the exact error message you’re seeing in your browser devtools console.

Answer (score 0):

It is CORS problem you should enable CORS to all in your API service, every platform have different config like in NodeJS, Apache, Nginx or etc.

You may look documentation about how activating CORS in web service here https://enable-cors.org/index.html

for request you could just doing something like this

```js
//jQuery <= 1.12.x
$.get(API_URL)
.success(function(response) {
    var res = $(response).find('YOUR_NODE');
})
.error(function(err) {

});

//jQuery > 1.12.x
$.get(API_URL)
.then(function(response) {
  var res = $(response).find('YOUR_NODE');
})
.catch(function(err) {

});
```

Regards.

Comment: I already enabled CORS by setting header  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'.  Is this not enough? Also I see from browser console the responseText shows **"Cannot POST"**.

Comment: @Mohan it means your router setting is not set to POST? What are you using? ASP.NET?